Autofill 1Password login details when page loads, without manually selecting 1Password account details?
When I load a webpage on Safari for macOS, the 1Password icon is shown in the login fields on pages where I have saved 1Password details + the correct URL. But no login details are automatically filled out in the form:

This requires 3 manual clicks: once on the icon, and then once to select which account details to fill (even if there's only one account), and then a final click of the "submit" button.
I seem to remember saved passwords, in the past, automatically loading within the textfield. Then I just need to click "Login" with no extra steps to first fill the username and password.
Is no-click autofill possible using the 1Password Safari Extension in modern macOS?

Well you do have to authenticate, which you can do by clicking on the icon in the text field or tapping COMMAND-BACKSLASH on the keyboard. 1Password will auto fill if it is sure it knows what login to use on the current web page. Which is why it is important to have an accurate URL field along with the username and password in 1Password

@SteveChambers each site has an accurate URL set. I want it to autofill on page load. Why does it need to "authenticate"?

Same behavior here, the user field does not auto-fill. Might be a question best asked 1P's support team.

Authentication by 1P, offers a second level of security over Keychain. And giving it a thumbprint takes literally 1 sec.

@SteveChambers I think the issue is that the OP has to click the icon for every webpage - if it was for authentication then they would only need to press the icon on the first web page

I have to do the same, only I use the keyboard shortcut (Command-Backspace) rather than trying to click on a tiny icon in the text field. It is rare that a web page fills automatically for me. Almost always I have to tap the command key sequence. I think @nohillside is right, this might be best asked of 1Password support. I have always found them responsive and helpful.
